# "Permission denied" error when running Ant build on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, ant, flexunit

I'm trying to run FlexUnit tests from Ant. Everything works fine on Windows but on Mac OS X, I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/ohassan/Projects/mongo/build.xml:347: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/player/mac/11.5/Flash Player Debugger.app" (in directory "/Users/ohassan/Projects/x"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at org.flexunit.ant.launcher.commands.player.CustomPlayerCommand.launch(Unknown Source)
    at org.flexunit.ant.tasks.TestRun.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.flexunit.ant.tasks.FlexUnitTask.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 20 more
```

Here's the Ant task:

```
<flexunit swf="${APP_BIN_DIR}/UnitTestingApp.swf" timeout="5000" toDir="${APP_REPORTS_DIR}" haltonfailure="false" verbose="true" localTrusted="false" command="${FLASH_PLAYER}" />
```

I gave 777 permissions to `${APP_BIN_DIR}`, `${APP_REPORTS_DIR}` and `Flash Player Debugger.app` but that didn't change anything. I also tried running the command `sudo ant` but that too had no effect on the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be running the folder named `.../Flash Player Debugger.app`. What you want to do is run the binary inside that folder. My best guess it is named `.../Flash Player Debugger.app/Contents/MacOS/Flash Player Debugger`.

Use Finder or some other file browser utility to show the contents of the folder `/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/player/mac/11.5/Flash Player Debugger.app/Contents/MacOS` to figure out the name of the executable file.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are not having required permission to the directory. You need to find that out for that you may use `namei`